# Physics.RaycastAll Find enemies with a tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity, what I'm trying to do is create a raycast which finds all objects tagged enemy, which are in front of my player, and if they are in that area when I press the F key it takes some health of each of them, could someone please help me? here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class meleeAttack : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject target;
public float attackTimer;
public float coolDown;

private RaycastHit hit;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    attackTimer = 0;
    coolDown = 0.5f;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


    if(attackTimer > 0)
        attackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(attackTimer < 0)
        attackTimer = 0;

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F)) {
        if(attackTimer == 0)
        Attack();
        attackTimer = coolDown;
    }
}

private void Attack() {



    float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, transform.position);

    Vector3 dir = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;

    float direction = Vector3.Dot(dir, transform.forward);

    Debug.Log(direction);
    if (distance < 3 && direction > 0.5) {
        enemyhealth eh = (enemyhealth)target.GetComponent("enemyhealth");
        eh.AddjustCurrentHealth(-10);
    }
}
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class enemyhealth : MonoBehaviour {

public int maxHealth = 100;
public int currentHealth = 100;


public float healthBarLength;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    healthBarLength = Screen.width / 2;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    AddjustCurrentHealth(0);
}

void OnGUI() {
    GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 40, healthBarLength, 20), currentHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
}

public void AddjustCurrentHealth(int adj){
    currentHealth += adj;
    if (currentHealth < 0)
        currentHealth = 0;

    if (currentHealth > maxHealth)
        currentHealth = maxHealth;

    if (maxHealth < 1)
        maxHealth = 1;

    healthBarLength = (Screen.width / 2) * (currentHealth / (float)maxHealth);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Attack(){
    int user_defined_layer = 8;  //use the 'User Layer' you created to define NPCs
    int layer_mask = 1 << user_defined_layer; 

    RaycastHit[] hits;

    // Get direction in front of your player
    Vector3 direction = transform.TransformPoint( Vector3.forward );
    hits = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, direction, Mathf.Infinity, layer_mask)

    foreach(RaycastHit hit in hits)
    {
        //NPC is hit, decrease his/her/its life
    }
}
```

It's best you don't try to derive a direction from your position to your NPCs.  Let Unity's ray cast engine handle the ray-NPC intersection testing for you.  This method does require that your NPC have a Collider.